# Did Deckard genuinely not care about the Rachael copy?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

Even without knowing that the Rachael copy would be shot if he rejected her, the Replicant that Wallace offered him was plainly programmed to love Deckard -- his rejection is obviously a message to Wallace that he is not swayed by this bribe, but Deckard also does not seem to care about the feelings of the Replicant.

Could it be that he assumes that the Rachael copy is a mindless robot, not really the equivalent of the original Rachael except in appearance? Or was his own daughter so important to him that he would even pretend not to care about the copy so that Wallace would have no leverage over him?

Comment: Well, she did have the wrong eye color.

Comment: There is no replacing the original Rachel- I always assumed that's what he meant when he said "her eyes were green".

Answer (score 11):

The [screenplay](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/blade_runner%20(2049).pdf) gives us a very nice insight into his thought process. Deckard loved Rachael. This *recreation/mirage/simulacrum* certainly reminds his of his pain and loss, but this isn't the person that he loved, merely a thing made to look like his dead wife.

> **NIANDER WALLACE:** *An Angel. Made again. For you.*
>
> Deckard fights the urge, can’t help but look. A perfect recreation of all he ever wanted is right in front of him. In the flesh. Instantly filled with longing. With disgust. Rachael steps close to Deckard. Lifts his chin. So they are face to face. We are transported back decades in seconds.
>
> **RACHAEL:** *Did you miss me?*
>
> Deckard says nothing.
>
> **RACHAEL:** *Don’t you love me?*
>
> The mirage utterly real and convincing. Deckard strains against pain of loss. Strains not to lose himself in a memory of lost joy... We fear he is tempted, when -- He tears his face from her hand. Rejecting the simulacrum.

Comment: He also visibly whinces and gets shocked/sad after the fact, which he wouldn't if he truly didn't care. This is a man who fell in love with a Replicant, the ultimate sign of caring for them and seeing them as 'people', so at the very least, he's just seen a person be killed pointlessly.

Comment: In calling it a "mirage" does this imply it is not the supremely intelligent and articulate Rachael of 30 years before, a truly sentient being but rather something hurriedly put together to look and sound like her but closer, it suddenly occurs to me, to the "friends" JF Sebastian creates?

Comment: @releseabe Sentient or not it is not the same person. If you married a twin and your wife died would her sister be a replacement? The copy does not have what is important to relationships: a shared past. Experience is what makes us who we are, not our flesh

Comment: @slebetman: If the sister was sentient, I sure would be careful of her feelings and avoid saying something that would cause her to be shot in the head. I am wondering, as I have asked before, if Deckard assumed the Rachael copy was not in fact sentient, like the toys made by Sebastian.

Answer (score 11):

**The scene illustrates how detached from humanity Wallace is.  It's not really about Deckard at all.**

> Could it be that he assumes that the Rachael copy is a mindless robot, not really the equivalent of the original Rachael except in appearance?

If the copy was *programmed* to love him then that's quite definitely going to repel a character who felt their was *genuine* love between him and the original.  It's also a copy of a younger Rachael when he's aged himself - quite jarring, perhaps off-putting.

To most people, I think, someone being *forced* to love them without free will would be repellent.  That the other individual was essentially unaware or not bothered by this would really make that worse as it means they have no sense of what choices they have lost.

Accepting the copy might also cheapen the memory of the original Rachael.  We will do anything to hold on to our feeling of love and affection, even after people die.  But we mourn the dead and that changes the way we feel about them.  A copy is not the same thing at all, but simply a reminder of what you actually lost.  A slave without free will here is worse.

It's more simply a sign that Wallace is without normal human feelings, perhaps a sociopath, who does not really understand love and confuses it with sex (as some people do).  To Wallace a copy is no different from the original if it does the same actions, regardless of why it does them.  That's not how "normal" people work - the why *is* important.

> Or was his own daughter so important to him that he would even pretend not to care about the copy so that Wallace would have no leverage over him?

Most people would die for their kids.  We're pretty much wired that way.  Passing up on the copy of Rachael pales in comparison to the risk to his child.

Even if you knew the copy would be killed if you decline, the danger from accepting is too great for someone like Deckard.  Your child versus a construction robbed of any free will - that's a choice a hard man like Deckard can make.  He's probably had to make many hard and even cruel decisions over the years.  One more is maybe easy.

He's a cop used to corruption and it's dangers.  That would be the expected attitude of a fundamentally good cop to an attempt at a bribe.  It's something they see every day.  It's remarkable that more police aren't corrupted given the temptations they face everyday, so Deckard is just being a cop here.

Cops survive by knowing the dangers of giving in to any of those temptations.  Once "they" get any hook into you, you're owned.  Deckard would have that knowledge as an instinct.

So it's a combination of a character that's resistant to corruption being offered something that's not really what he wants and involving a risk to his kid.  It's almost inevitable that Deckard would turn down the offer.

The offer is really there just to illustrate how detached from human feeling that Wallace has become.  It's not the only scene illustrating this.  What differntiates K and Deckard from Wallace is some connection to "normal" empathy.  Wallace never does.

This scene is IMO all about Wallace.

Comment: Funny though, that Wallace jeers Deckard accusing him of being programmed to love _her_.

Comment: @Möoz The first _Blade Runner_ is famously ambiguous about whether Deckard is himself a replicant. (Yes, the director tried to retcon things decades later, but shared culture doesn't work like that.) Wallace is desperate to unlock the secret of Tyrell's replicants so he can literally rule the galaxy. Wallace's statement to Deckard that he & Rachel were programmed to fall in love is both an attempt to reinforce the real-world after-the-fact retcon of the first movie, and an in-story attack on Deckard's grasp on sanity (a pretty good one, too). Hence Deckard's reply that he "knows what is real."

Comment: @Tom I've never bought into the whole "Deckard is a replicant" idea.  The second movie doesn't really show that IMO.  Wallace is attempting psychological manipulation here and there's no reason to read more into it than that.  The whole "you've no choice really, why not just go with the flow and make the best of it" thing is standard for interrogation/bribery scenes.  IMO Deckard as a replicant is a concept litterally *sold* by Ridley Scott and Co because they wanted to create some minor controversy to increase sales.

Comment: This scene systematically shows that Wallace himself would utterly fail the Voight-Kampff test: (1) freakish cybernetic eyes; (2) constant pontificating like he's dictating his own Bible often sounds like an AI failing a Turing test; (3) his gambit with Rebecca v2 reveals total lack of empathy. I don't mention it to press the Deckard point, I just wanted to add _in-universe_ analysis of Wallace to this already excellent answer. (But, incidentally: Wallace being an edge case somewhat mirrors how BR'82 creates philosophically useful ambiguity about Deckard's nature.)

Comment: @Tom, Yeah, he would. I watched the movie Titticutt Follies and a related film about mental institutions and I thought how hard it would be to get out when the tests and decisions are so subjective and in particular, how hard it would be for the doctors running things in such facilities to get out of one once committed.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, there is a variation of this Faustian bargain scene from *The Edge of Human* by K.W. Jeter where the real human template from which the replicant was modeled, Sarah Tyrell, proposes to take Rachael's place, but Deckard does not agree (`p.279`):

> "No..." He spoke without turning to look at Sarah's image.

> "I knew it would be this way. You prefer the dead to the living, the fake to the real.  The memory...to me." Her voice became harsher and more grating.

There is another line in the book about how a memory is pure. So in this interpretation, nothing can compete with the memory of Rachael. Deckard doesn't even need to consider. I think 2049 or Harrison Ford conveys more depth in his portrayal of Deckard, and more is at stake than his personal future but still keeps the same drive/motivation. When he understands Wallace basically is the devil he can't betray his love to make a deal, whatever the terms.